# Can we change iPhone app binary after it has been upload and waiting for upload

Tags: iphone, ipad, binary, app-store

I have uploaded my application recently but wants to change some minor things in it as per client requirement and wants to reupload it in appstore..Is it possible and how? Can anyone please tell me regarding this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to 'reject the binary' in iTunes connect under your application info, then you can select 'prepare for upload' in order to upload a new binary.

Comment: It should be noted that although you can do this it will put your app at the back of the line in terms of app store approval.